# JUNIT Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, testing, junit

it's my first time using JUNIT and I literally cannot get it to work.

I've got a person class, in which has firstName and lastName, and a test class in which I need to test the methods.  Everytime I attempt to test one though, if i've wrote a test for the particular method, it fails.

Here is my code.

**Person Class**

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;    

    public Person (String a, String b) {
        firstName = a;
        lastName = b;
    }

    public String getfirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setfirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getlastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setlastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

**Person Test class**

```
public class PersonTest {
    Person p1;

    public PersonTest() {
        Person p1 = new Person ("Thomas", "Brown");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {}

    @After
    public void tearDown() {}

    @Test
    public void testGetfirstName() {
        assertEquals("Thomas", p1.getfirstName());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetfirstName() {}

    @Test
    public void testGetlastName() {
        assertEquals("Brown", p1.getlastName());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetlastName() {}

    @Test
    public void testToString() {
        assertEquals("Thomas Brown", p1.toString());
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Move the creation of `Person p1...` to your `@Before` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the right way to do it:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    p1 = new Person ("Thomas", "Brown");
}
```

You have 2 problems in your code.

```
public PersonTest() {
    Person p1 = new Person ("Thomas", "Brown");
}
```

This creates a local variable and your field `p1` stays `null`.

The second is that in your `setUp` method you do not initialize `p1`.

The method you annotate with `@Before` will run before every test to you should put the initialization there. I also suggest to use more descriptive names so you should change `p1` to `target` or something like that.

**Edit:** For your `set...` methods you can do something like this:

```
public class PersonTest {
    private static final String TEST_FIRST_NAME = "some name";

    Person target;

    // ...
    @Test
    public void testSetFirstName() {
        target.setFirstName(TEST_FIRST_NAME);
        Assert.assertEquals(target.getFirstName(), TEST_FIRST_NAME);
    }
}
```

At that point you can assume that `getFirstName` works since you have a test for it as well.

*A sidenote:* I think you don't have to test getters and setters as long as you generate them with Eclipse. It is just unnesessary.

Comment: Excellent thanks. I'm also confused about how I go about testing set methods? Could you point me in the right direction with that?

Comment: You may want to test your accessors/mutators if your production class is asserting inputs and/or valid state.

Comment: That's the job of a validator class or something like that, no?

Comment: True, but not all systems make use of external validator classes for simple things like `null`s and empty strings.

Comment: It might be an overkill but on a previous system I was working on we created a `NonNullParametrized` aspect which checked all methods in the business facade and threw an exception if the user supplied `null`. In this case we only had to test the aspect not all methods. At the end of the day it was much less work for the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
Person p1 = new Person ("Thomas", "Brown"); //this is local variable
```

to

```
 p1 = new Person ("Thomas", "Brown");// and this will use the instance variable
```

Comment: While it is correct to remove this aliasing, it is usually bad form to initialize the class under test in a test constructor (where it is only created once) instead of in a `@Before` method (where it is initialized for each `@Test`). If you use the constructor method *and* you modify the class under test at any point, you're introducing side-effects for all of your `@Test` methods.

Comment: Good note, actually I am not familiar to `JUnit`, I just knew the reason of *NullPointerException* :) 
But thanks for the good information, hope it'll be useful for him.