# JUnit Null Pointer Exception When Declaring in setUpClass or setUp

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

Currently I am setting up basic JUnit tests in the following two manners which both give me null pointer exceptions when running the tests at the line where I call c.add():

```
public class CalculatorTest {

    Calculator c;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        c = new Calculator();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        System.out.println("add");
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = c.add(a, b);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }
....
```

The second way:

```
public class CalculatorTest {
    
    static Calculator c;
    
    public CalculatorTest() {
    }
    
    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUpClass() {
        c = new Calculator();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        System.out.println("add");
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = c.add(a, b);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }
...
```

This link: [JUNIT Null Pointer Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978692/junit-null-pointer-exception)
suggests to me I'm doing this right but I'm still getting the null pointer exception.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you verify (by setting a break point in your setup-methods) that those methods are called before tests are executed?

Comment: Looks like those methods aren't called at all. My first guess was maybe I was mixing up Junit4/5 but I confirmed that I'm using 5. Why wouldn't it be called?

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing up Junit4 and Junit5? Can you remove the `public`-modifiers from the `@Test`-methods? If the tests are not executed or an error is thrown complaining that the tests are not public, then a Junit4 engine is used.

Comment: No tests are run when I remove the public but now I'm more confused why its using Junit 4 when the 5.6.0 jar is referenced in my project dependencies and I'm using "import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach"

Comment: The import is only the API. The version of JUnit depends on the engine loaded at runtime. Can you share your project? Do you use maven? In this case: the `pom.xml` should be sufficient to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have my pom file above

Comment: Can you try to only add `<dependency><groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId><artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId><version>5.6.0</version></dependency>` as junit dependency to your `pom.xml`? Also, how do you start your test?

Comment: Tried removing all besides that dependency with no success. I just right click my file to test file in NetBeans. My tests do run if i use "private final Calculator c = new Calculator()" outside rather then trying to use @BeforeAll.

Comment: Seems like netbeans tries to run the tests with JUnit 4. Can you try to execute the tests through maven by calling `mvn test` in the project's root directory?

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Turing85 I gave up on making this work in NetBeans but got it up and running in eclipse without issues so I'm just going to go forward with that.

Answer (score 0):

Calculator is Class Under Test, therefore, you don't need to do

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    c = new Calculator();
}
```

You can declare c like this:

```
Calculator c = new Calculator();
```

and add @Test method as usual.